How to read XML file by AWS S3 in IICS?
In IICS, I want to read XML file from Amazon S3, and load the record to salesforce.After executing the mappingtask, execute a command statement to back up the XML file in s3.
I create a AWS S3 Connector, then add a hierarchy Parser to parse XML.
In the source settings, set the type to flat file and the file name to sample.txt. In this file, the first line is PATH, and the second line is the S3 path and SML file name. This approach can be executed in the local environment using the file connector, but it always fails when using the AWS S3 connector.
